# A weird while issue

Tags: php, while-loop

I have 3 `while`s in the code below. Before this I had just 1 `while` but after expanding the CMS it doesn't want to display the content anymore, I'm not sure what is causing the bug.

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE public="1"');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$url = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM websettings WHERE setting="url"');
$url->execute();
$urlresult = $url->get_result();

$startpagina = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM websettings WHERE setting="startpagina"');
$startpagina->execute();
$startresult = $startpagina->get_result();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        while ($urlrow = $urlresult->fetch_assoc()) {
            while ($startrow = $startresult->fetch_assoc()) {
                if(!empty($_GET[$urlrow['value']])) {
                    if(isset($_GET[$urlrow['value']]) && $_GET[$urlrow['value']] == $row['name']) {
                        ?>
                            <h1><?php echo $row["heading"]; ?></h1>
                            <?php echo ubbreplace($row["content"]); ?>
                        <?php
                    }
                } else {
                    header("Location: ?" . $urlrow['value'] . "=" . $startrow["value"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Er zijn nog geen pagina's aangemaakt.";
}
?>
```

Can someone please help me out? I'm really trying to fix it, nothing really works.

---

**SOLUTION**

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE public="1"');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $url = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM websettings WHERE setting="url"');
        $url->execute();
        $urlresult = $url->get_result();
        while ($urlrow = $urlresult->fetch_assoc()) {
            $startpagina = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM websettings WHERE setting="startpagina"');
            $startpagina->execute();
            $startresult = $startpagina->get_result();
            while ($startrow = $startresult->fetch_assoc()) {
                if(!empty($_GET[$urlrow['value']])) {
                    if(isset($_GET[$urlrow['value']]) && $_GET[$urlrow['value']] == $row['name']) {
                        ?>
                            <h1><?php echo $row["heading"]; ?></h1>
                            <?php echo ubbreplace($row["content"]); ?>
                        <?php
                    }
                } else {
                    header("Location: ?" . $urlrow['value'] . "=" . $startrow["value"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Er zijn nog geen pagina's aangemaakt.";
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you have only 1 while, what you have currently will do nothing if there are less than 3 rows and skip the first 3 if there more.

Comment: Do you know which loop you are failing in? Can you put an echo in each one to narrow it down?

Comment: @nerdlyist I got the content when I echoed `$row['name']` in the first `while`, updated my post, the issue might be there somewhere?

Comment: Add one in each loop. make it like `echo "Test loop 1";` etc. You are nested so the first one will only run after you finish the inner loops. As suggest in the answer let us see your data sets would help.

Comment: @nerdlyist with data sets you mean a screen of the database setup?

Comment: Maybe not the whole table but a subset. Something we can use to understand the flow.

Comment: @nerdlyist I have fixed the problem and have posted a solution in my post

Comment: Your solution is obvious working (and now the error is clear) - but imagine you have 100 entries per table - does it make sence to fetch 1.000.000 entries, Iterate 1.000.000 times (worstcase), until you have the desired post?

Comment: As @dognose states you should be considering performance. Look into Big O Notation this is not going to scale well. Also you can post an answer and accept it if you are satisfied there. Put a little more explanation into the changes.

Comment: @dognose Well I don't really know how I can make it better, can you maybe give me an example?

Comment: @J.Doe Can you provide the 2 tables `paginas` and `websettings` (their columns and if possible "relations") and add some example data? Then one could maybe write a single query for that. (http://sqlfiddle.com/ is great for sharing this information - Just run "SHOW CREATE TABLE `tablename`" for each table and post the text "there".)

Comment: @dognose Hmm I can only see 1/10 of the code and it won't let me expand that, is it possible to send you a screenshot of the table?

Answer (score 1):

Get Rid of the "dynamic" parametername - hide it behind a parameter you can access in a static way:

`?page=index`

becomes

```
`?p_mode=page&p_selection=index`
```

or whatever.(Do you REALLY need `page` to be dynamic? - I guess not.)

Then, you can easily use a single query (Imagine the first 2 parameters are not hardcoded, but used from the GET-Parameters `p_mode` and `p_selection`):

```
set @setting_name = "page"; 
set @setting_value = "index"; 

SELECT 
  p.*
FROM
  paginas p
right JOIN
  websettings ws 
ON 
  ws.`value` = p.`name`
WHERE 
  p.`public` = 1 AND
  ws.`setting` = @setting_name AND
  ws.`value` = @setting_value;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce97a/2

However, note that your "setting name" is useless in this tiny example, as it only joins on the value.

(See this example, leading to a wrong result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4abb0/1)

So - if you want different keys, add them to the `paginas` table, make them (and the value) a unique pair:

```
public | heading | content | key      | value
1        Test      Test      mode       index
1        Test 2    Test 2    anotherKey index
```

and query them in a single run.

Add the End: Please read this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Try to ask about your *actual problem* rather than the solution *you think might work* in the future.